# Problems with making this table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have tried to make a html table but can really figure out how to make it look like this(image). i cant figure out the css

Can anybody help?[picture of the table im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl9Ws.png)

Comment: what the problem ?

Comment: Show us the code you got

Comment: I have made the table, but i cant figure out how to only set border around the data. Like not around the table headers and not around the names

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-width: 3px;
}

td {
  border-right-style: dashed;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right-style: solid;
}

td:nth-last-child(-n+2),
th:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top-style: solid;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Mandag</th>
      <th>Tirsdag</th>
      <th>Onsdag</th>
      <th>Torsdag</th>
      <th>Fredag</th>
      <th>Lordag</th>
      <th>Sondag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Carlo</th>
      <td>Fodbold</td>
      <td>Panfojte</td>
      <td>Fodbold</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Gitte</th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Basket</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Basket</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Anne</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Sang</td>
      <td>Handbold</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```